# ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource' could not find a non-generic method 'Insert' that has parameters

Tags: asp.net

i have a grid view with editing enabled so when i edit a user i get an error:

ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'Update' that has parameters: 
i am also using a details view to insert a new user to by database but when i try to insert it says

ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'Insert' that has parameters:

Comment: how does your insert and update method looks like ? And for delete you have only last name parameter?

Comment: i using detail view with defult mode as insert

Comment: Just remove all the parameters from the `InsertParameters` list. Basically you are passing your parameters twice - as bound fields and as insert parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all methods [SelectMethod, UpdateMethod, DeleteMethod, SelectCountMethod, InsertMethod] used by the ObjectDataSource are typed correctly.

Check to verify the Type ( sTableAdapters.SyTableAdapter ) actually contains the Update and Insert method

Do these methods contain exact parameters as pointed in the error, both in number and order. Remember that the order of parameters mean a lot for ObjectDataSource .

Comment: Note your attribute DataField="Last Name" has a blank between tokens but the parameter Name="First_Name" han an underscore this may be the cause of the mismatch; anyway it could help the diagnosis of the problem looking at the parametes in the Insert() and Update() method of the code of your TableAdapters.SyTableAdapter class (i.e the signatures of thes methods).